# java.lang.NullPointerException with Scala regex

Tags: scala, sbt

I am having a bizarre behavior in my scala project when I try to run it from sbt.

The line that throws a java.lang.NullPointerException is this:

```
id <- urlReg.findFirstIn(line).map(_.split("/").lift(3))
```

It is inside a for-comprehension:

```
for {
  line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()
  id <- urlReg.findFirstIn(line).map(_.split("/").lift(3))
  dateString <- dateReg.findFirstMatchIn(line).map(_.group(1))
} yield {...}
```

When I test this line at a scala console, I see that `findFirstIn` returns an `Option[String]`, so it should return a `None` or `Some[String]` and never throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

This code ran for awhile without throwing the exception and then started throwing the exception.

urlReg is 
     `val urlReg = "[GET,POST,DELETE,PUT]\\s{1}[\\w/]+".r`

A sample line of input is

```
val sampleLine = """10.10.6.90 - - 15/Aug/2016:23:59:20 -0500 "GET /ecf8427e/b443dc7f/71f28176/174ef735/1dd4d421 HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-" 7 "10.10.1.231, 10.10.6.90" -"""
```

I expect there is some incompatibility in my setup. I am running:

- MacOS Sierra 10.12.1.
- sbt 0.13.13
- scala 2.12.1
- java 1.8.0_112

Comment: `_.split("/")` could throw a NPE if `.findFirstIn(line)` returns `Some(null)`. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I tried it without the `split` call, running  `id <- urlReg.findFirstIn(line)`. I got the same error.

Comment: Check what your input is. What is urlReg?

Comment: I have gotten this line of code to work. Then it stopped working.

urlReg is 

`val urlReg = "[GET,POST,DELETE,PUT]\\s{1}[\\w/]+".r`

A sample input line is:

`  val sampleLine = """10.10.6.90 - - 15/Aug/2016:23:59:20 -0500 "GET /ecf8427e/b443dc7f/71f28176/174ef735/1dd4d421 HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-" 7 "10.10.1.231, 10.10.6.90" -"""`

Comment: Does it fail when you give it that exact sample input?

Comment: I rearranged the code a bit so that I could print out the line before running the regex on it. That is indeed the first line of the file and the one that is throwing the null pointer exception. It is NOT throwing the same exception when I paste the sample line and the regex into a repl console and try it out.   It only happens when I run my program with sbt.

Comment: @JacobLyles Input file may have unexpected characters depending on where it's created. I had similar problems when file modifiers use different OS.

Answer (score 1):

I also believe that it is due to some Option[String] type that are returned by 2 of the function in your script.

Would you consider using a map/filter combination like the one below:

```
val faultyLine = """10.10.6.90 - - 15/Aug/2016:23:59:20 -0500 "GET /ecf8427eb443dc7f71f28176174ef7351dd4d421 HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-" 7 "10.10.1.231, 10.10.6.90" -"""
val line= """10.10.6.90 - - 15/Aug/2016:23:59:20 -0500 "GET /ecf8427e/b443dc7f/71f28176/174ef735/1dd4d421 HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-" 7 "10.10.1.231, 10.10.6.90" -"""

val lines = List(line,line,faultyLine)

lines.map(line => (urlReg.findFirstIn(line).map(_.split("/").lift(3))).match {
case Some(Some(a)) => a 
case _ => null
}).filter( _ != null )
```

You should be able to replace the map/filter by a flatMap but I was not successful at it. That should simplify it and get rid of the ugly nulls in there.

Good luck!